# Get value zero if data is not there in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, generate-series

I have a table `employee` in Postgres:

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT month_last_date,number_of_cases,reopens,csat
FROM employee
WHERE month_last_date >=(date('2017-01-31') - interval '6 month')
AND   month_last_date <= date('2017-01-31')
AND agent_id='analyst' 
AND name='SAM';
```

Output:

[image: Output I get]

But if data is not in table for other month I want column value as **`0`**.

[image: Required output]

Comment: Please post data as *text*, never as image. And always include your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Generate all dates you are interested in, `LEFT JOIN` to the table and default to `0` with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  -- see below
       i.month_last_date
     , COALESCE(number_of_cases, 0) AS number_of_cases  -- see below
     , COALESCE(reopens, 0)         AS reopens
     , COALESCE(csat, 0)            AS csat
FROM  (
   SELECT date '2017-01-31' - i * interval '1 mon' AS month_last_date
   FROM   generate_series(0, 5) i  -- see below
   ) i
LEFT   JOIN employee e ON e.month_last_date = i.month_last_date
                      AND e.agent_id = 'analyst'  -- see below
                      AND e.name = 'SAM';
```

#### Notes

If you add or subtract an `interval` of 1 month and the same day does not exist in the target month, Postgres defaults to the latest existing day of that moth. So this works as desired, you get the last day of each month:

```
SELECT date '2017-12-31' - i * interval '1 mon'  -- note 31
FROM   generate_series(0,11) i;
```

But this ***does not***, you'd get the 28th of each month:

```
SELECT date '2017-02-28' - i * interval '1 mon'  -- note 28
FROM   generate_series(0,11) i;
```

The safe alternative is to subtract 1 day from the first day of the next month, like [@Oto demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019010/939860). Related:

- [Daily average for the month (needs number of days in month)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240571/daily-average-for-the-month-needs-number-of-days-in-month/19241711#19241711)

Here are two optimized ways to generate a series of last days of the month - *up to and including* a given month:

#### 1.

```
SELECT (timestamp '2017-01-01' - i * interval '1 month')::date - 1 AS month_last_date
FROM   generate_series(-1, 10) i;  -- generate 12 months, off-by-1
```

Input is the ***first day of the month*** - or calculate it from a given `date` or `timestamp` with [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2017-01-17')::date AS this_mon1
```

Subtracting an `interval` from a `date` produces a `timestamp`. After the cast back to `date` we can simply subtract an `integer` to subtract days.

#### 2.

```
SELECT m::date - 1 AS month_last_date
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2017-02-01' - interval '11 month'  -- for 12 months
                     , timestamp '2017-02-01'
                     , interval '1 mon') m;
```

Input is the ***first day of the next month*** - or calculate it from any given date or timestamp with:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp '2017-01-17' + interval '1 month')::date AS next_mon1
```

Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)
- [Create list with first and last day of month for given period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583877/create-list-with-first-and-last-day-of-month-for-given-period/21584418#21584418)

Not sure you actually need **`DISTINCT`**. Typically, `(agent_id, month_last_date)` would be defined unique, then remove `DISTINCT` ...

Be sure to use the **`LEFT JOIN`** correctly. Join conditions go into the join clause, ***not*** the `WHERE` clause:

- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)

Finally, default to `0` with [**`COALESCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) where `NULL` values are filled in by the `LEFT JOIN`.
**Note** that `COALESCE` cannot distinguish between actual `NULL` values from the right table and NULL values filled in for missing rows. If your columns are not defined `NOT NULL`, there may be ambiguity to address.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you need generate last days of all last 6 months, before certain date. (before "2017-01-31" in this case).

If I correctly understand, then you can use this query, which generates all of these days

```
 SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', mnth) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE 
 FROM 
 generate_series('2017-01-31'::date - interval '6 month', '2017-01-31'::date, '1 month') as mnth;
```

You just need `LEFT JOIN` this query to your existing query, and you get desirable result

Please note that this will returns 7 record (days), not 6.